# How to add -OutputPath parameter to Powershell script being called from batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Using a batch file to call a Powershell script (this part is working and saving the output files locally):

```bash
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File ""%~dpn0.ps1 -Update""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Trying to add in a parameter to redirect the output of the script to a folder (per the code comments it can be to a local or UNC path):
`-OutputPath Z:\Current`
Have tried inserting it everywhere I can think of in the script, cannot get it to work; am thinking it should go in like this(?):

```bash
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File ""%~dpn0.ps1 -OutputPath Z:\Current""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Here is where the output path is determined in the code:

```
# If -OutputPath not specified, set default
If (-not($OutputPath)) {
    Switch ($OSPlatform) {
        "Windows" {
            $OutputPath = "$env:PUBLIC\Documents\ Compliance"
            if (!(Test-Path $OutputPath)) {
                $null = New-Item -Path $(Split-Path -Path $OutputPath -Parent) -Name $(Split-Path -Path $OutputPath -Leaf) -ItemType Directory
            }
        }
        "Linux" {
            $OutputPath = "/opt/STIG_Compliance"
            if (!(Test-Path $OutputPath)) {
                sudo mkdir $OutputPath
            }
        }
    }


}
```

From what I can find online, the `-OutputPath Z:\Current` should come immediately after the `.ps1` command, but not sure where it should be inserted amongst the other options being used in the batch file.

The script is not throwing off any errors, but is running and saving the output in the default locatin.  I am not that well-versed in Powershell; am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Have you defined an `$OutputPath` parameter in your `param()` block in the script?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to pass the **OutputPath** parameter to your PowerShell script through the command line argument -File. I believe the correct way to pass parameters to a PowerShell script is to include them in the argument list of the PowerShell command.

You could update your command to include the OutputPath parameter in the argument list, like this:

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""', '-OutputPath', 'Z:\Current' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Also, make sure to update your PowerShell script to properly use the **OutputPath** parameter, like this:

```
# If -OutputPath not specified, set default
if (-not $OutputPath) {
    switch ($OSPlatform) {
        "Windows" {
            $OutputPath = "$env:PUBLIC\Documents\Compliance"
            if (!(Test-Path $OutputPath)) {
                $null = New-Item -Path $(Split-Path -Path $OutputPath -Parent) -Name $(Split-Path -Path $OutputPath -Leaf) -ItemType Directory
            }
        }
        "Linux" {
            $OutputPath = "/opt/STIG_Compliance"
            if (!(Test-Path $OutputPath)) {
                sudo mkdir $OutputPath
            }
        }
    }
}

# Redirect output to the specified output path
if ($OutputPath) {
    $OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $OutputPath -ChildPath "output.txt"
    Write-Output "Writing output to $OutputFile"
    # Your code to generate output here
    # ...
    Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -InputObject "Output data"
}
else {
    # Your code to generate output here
    # ...
}
```

Hopefully this helps ya.